# Store multiple corpus via for loop by different names

Tags: r, for-loop, text-mining, tm, corpus

I have multiple text documents per ticker which I want to store as an individual corpus. 
I've read about creating ''lists in lists'', but this doesn't work for me. For example, ''text mining and termdocumentmatrix'' give the following error: *no applicable method for 'TermDocumentMatrix' applied to an object of class "list*.

I could possibly put everything within the for loop, but that's not what I want since I want some flexibility to play with the corpus.

Could someone help me out how I can effectively work around this problem? My code is below. Thank you in advance!

```
Stocks <- list("AAPL", "AMZN", "BIG", "BYD", "CTWS", "EAT", "FB", "GOOG", "GRMC", "HRL", "MGM", "MSFT",
               "NEM", "PKS", "RGLD", "SCCO", "SLP", "TCO", "USGL", "WDFC"
)

BigList <- list()
for (stock in Stocks) {
  filepath <- file.path("C:/Users/......./Stocks10K", stock)
  a <- Corpus(DirSource(filepath))
  a <- tm_map(a, removePunctuation)
  a <- tm_map(a, removeNumbers)
  a <- tm_map(a, tolower)
  a <- tm_map(a, removeWords, stopwords("en"))
  a <- tm_map(a, stripWhitespace)
  name <- paste('Data:', stock, sep='')
  tmp <- list(Text = a)
  BigList[name] <- tmp
  rm(tmp, stock, name, filepath, a)
}

#Create Term Document Matrix and create Matrix
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(BigList['Data:AAPL'])
m <- as.matrix(tdm)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've done everything right, except getting your entry out of `BigList`. `[` will return a list (containing one element in your case) - you need `[[` instead.  Try:

```
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(BigList[['Data:AAPL']])
```

instead.

https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Indexing has more info, including this note (in case what I said above isn't clear):

> For lists, one generally uses [[ to select any single element, whereas
>   [ returns a list of the selected elements.

Comment: It worked! I knew the solution couldn't be that hard. Storing everything in a big list definitely has my preference, I just didn't know how to access it properly. Thank you!

Comment: No problem - happy to help